# Is this a python antipattern? 'import foo.foo as foo' shadows the rest of the foo package

Tags: python, module, package, init, shadowing

Say I start off with package `pack` that contains a module `foo.py`.

```
pack/
pack/__init__.py
pack/foo.py        # Defines class Foo
```

But for reasons, I decide I need to move `foo.py` to a subpackage. Perhaps my foo is very strong and I need more functionality to manage it. Since the subpackage is all about foo, I name it `foo` as well, so now we have

```
pack/
pack/__init__.py
pack/foo
pack/foo/__init__.py
pack/foo/foo.py        # Defines class Foo
```

"Ah", I say, "I can make things backward compatible and avoid inflicting on calling code the excessive foo-ness of `pack.foo.foo.Foo()` with the following import in `pack/__init__.py`...

```
$ cat pack/__init__.py
import foo.foo as foo
```

...so that I can use `pack.foo.Foo()` to initialize a `Foo`."

Unfortunately, this means the module `foo.py` shadows the rest of the `foo` package, so that only the contents of `pack/foo/foo.py` are visible.

That's all expected behavior, my question is, would this rise to the level of an antipattern? It seems like at each step the decisions make a certain sense, so it's sort of an easy road to wander down (I have a couple of times) until all that additional functionality that motivated the subpackage says "hey what about us?"

Is there a pythonic way to turn a module into a subpackage like this, taking into account naming and backwards compatibility? The `foo.foo.Foo` in particular is irksome (`datetime.datetime` notwithstanding) but maybe the answer is "just deal with it" and eat the backwards incompatibility. I toyed with putting a `from foo import *` somewhere, but that seems wrong. Or am I missing some simple solution?

Comment: I think the obvious answer is: Don't name things with silly nested names like `foo.foo.Foo` in the first place. While namespaces are one honking great idea (let's do more of those!), nested namespaces beyond a level or two are annoying. If you *really* need to have nested packages, at least give them meaningful (non-duplicated) names at each level.

Comment: I most definitely concur about deep namespaces, but this is only one extra level, and examples abound (os.path, logging config, the redundantly redundant datetime.datetime). It doesn't even have to be a desire to do it, more a seduction at each step along the way. :)

Comment: yes, but this problem does not exist if you have `foo.foo`. Why are the contents of `foo.foo` not in `foo`? `datetime.datetime` is not a module. And it is very badly named as well.

Comment: Antti, in this scenario the contents that end up in foo.foo start out in foo, but then foo gets large enough that it deserves more than one file, so the module foo gets expanded into a subpackage foo. But the subpackage is so foo-ey it gets named foo, while the original module foo remains. Then backward compatibility rears its head. This is one of those "only two hard problems". http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html

Answer (score 0):

Despite my comment that the *real* solution is to avoid such deeply nested namespaces, I think the best approach to solving the issue once you are in it is probably to move the contents of `pack/foo/foo.py` into the `pack/foo/__init__.py` file. That way you can still have other modules within the `pack.foo` package, but also access the `Foo` class and whatever else was in `foo.py` from the same place as before (`pack.foo`).